# Unable to load a pandas dataframe having a JSON column into mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, django, pandas, graphql

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this when I print it out in the terminal in pycharm. This is inside a django project

```
`     exception              recommendation    time_dimension_id
0  {'exception': []}               0                217
1  {'exception': []}               0                218
2  {'exception': []}               0                219
3  {'exception': []}             546                220
4  {'exception': []}            2876                221
5  {'exception': []}            7855                222
6  {'exception': [{'error...  , 5041                223
7  {'exception': []}              57                224
8  {'exception': []}               0                225
9  {'exception': []}               0                226
10 {'exception': []}               0                227
11 {'exception': []}             108                228
12 {'exception': []}               0                229
13 {'exception': []}              12                230
14 {'exception': []}               0                231
15 {'exception': []}               0                232
16 {'exception': []}               0                233
17 {'exception': []}               0                234
18 {'exception': []}               0                235
19 {'exception': []}               0                236
20 {'exception': []}               0                237
21 {'exception': []}               0                238
22 {'exception': []}               0                239
23 {'exception': []}               0                240
`
```

I tried to insert this dataframe into a table using the below code.

```
connection = engine.connect()
    df.to_sql('table_name', con=connection, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Then, I got the below error

> graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (3140, 'Invalid JSON text: "Missing a name for object member." at position 1 in value for column \'fact_exception.exception\'.') [SQL: 'INSERT INTO fact_exception (exception, recommendation, time_dimension_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: (({'exception': []}, 0, 217), ({'exception': []}, 0, 218), ({'exception': []}, 0, 219), ({'exception': []}, 546, 220), ({'exception': []}, 2876, 221), ({'exception': []}, 7855, 222), ({'exception': [{'error': '', 'fatal': 'com.materiall.recommender.cache.MetaLU:58 - Cannot Load metaLU for express_com-u1456154309768com.materiall.conn ... (6923 characters truncated) ... "resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"null","index_uuid":"*na*","index":"null"},"status":404}\n', 'time_stamp': '2020-02-11T06:26:23,694'}]}, 5041, 223), ({'exception': []}, 57, 224)  ... displaying 10 of 24 total bound parameter sets ...  ({'exception': []}, 0, 239), ({'exception': []}, 0, 240))] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Below the relevant code used to create the dataframe column-wise

```
        fact_excep["exception"] = excep_df_column #this is a list of dictionaries
        fact_excep["recommendation"] = recommendation_col #this is a list integers
        fact_excep["time_dimension_id"] = time_dimension_id_col #this is a list integers
        # print(fact_excep)
    connection = engine.connect()
    fact_excep.to_sql("fact_exception", con=connection, if_exists="append", index=False)
    response = "fact_exception data created"
    return response
```

Below is the model

```
class FactException (models.Model):    #this is the model
fact_exception_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
time_dimension_id = models.ForeignKey(
    TimeDimension, null=False, blank=True, db_column="time_dimension_id", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
recommendation = models.IntegerField()
exception = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)

objects = models.Manager()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'fact_exception'

def __int__(self):
    return self.fact_exception_id
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How is your `exception` column defined? What's your model?

Comment: Note you can't use single quotes in JSON, you have to use double quotes. So `{'exception': []}` is not valid JSON.

Comment: @dirkgroten , That is the output I got when I printed the dataframe

Comment: I will add the model to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column does not contain valid JSON:

```
{'exception': [{'error': '', 'fatal': 'com.materiall.recommender.cache.MetaLU:58 - Cannot Load metaLU for express_com-u1456154309768com.materiall.conn...'}]}
# and
{'exception': []}
```

is not valid because the keys and strings have single quotes, which isn't valid in JSON. You should use double quotes and the whole column should be strings:

```
'{"exception": [{"error": "", "fatal": "com.materiall.recommender.cache.MetaLU:58 - Cannot Load metaLU for express_com-u1456154309768com.materiall.conn..."}]}'
# and
'{"exception": []}'
```

You're setting the column using a list of python dicts, but since you use `df.to_sql()` to save, this requires your data frame to have the exact data required by the SQL query. If you were using your model, you could just assign `my_factexception.exception = some_dict` and it would save as JSON. But you're essentially bypassing the Django ORM that knows your model and knows how to map a dictionary to a `jsonb` field so you have to do it yourself.

So when you set the values for your exception column, use `json.dumps(some_dict)` to create json strings.

Comment: I didn't use single quotes when I created the dataframe. It's the output of the print statement and the error message that contains single quotes.

Comment: Show the input then. It looks like your column is a python dictionary, which is ok if you were to assign it directly to the field (`my_factexception.exception = some_dict`), but since you're using raw sql, you should use a string. Did you pass a string to your data frame or a dict?

Comment: I will add the code showing my input into the dataframe.

Comment: I passed data, column-wise into the dataframe, the JSON column of the dataframe gets a list of dictionaries.

Comment: you should pass it a list of strings (in json format), use `json.dumps()` for that. `df.to_sql()` is just raw sql, it doesn't take into account your model (it doesn't know your model), so the data needs to be exactly what can be passed to the SQL statement.

Comment: No, `json.loads()` is from json to python, you want `json.dumps()` to do the opposite.